# Deleting CloudWatch event rule still keeps it attached to lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is attached CloudWatch event, and once the event triggers - lambda will then delete the rule via the following code:

```
var paramsTarget = {
    Ids: [ /* required */
      `Target_ForOrder_${order_id}`
      /* more items */
    ],
    Rule: `ForOrder_${order_id}` /* required */
  };
  cloudwatchevents.removeTargets(paramsTarget, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack)
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      var params = {
        Name: `ForOrder_${order_id}`
      };
      cloudwatchevents.deleteRule(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
          console.log("Delete cloudwatch rule successful! - data: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
        callback(null, result);
      });
    }
  });
```

This code snippet deletes it successfully from CloudWatch event from the rules, but it still attached to my lambda you can refer to the attached image for more explanation[image]. Is there a way I can delete cloudwatch event from my lambda target programmatically?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Hoping there is no functional impact of this.

Answer (score 0):

You even have to remove the function-use permission using the lambda client provided by the [sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#removePermission-property).
 Just follow these steps to completely remove cloud watch event rule:

1. Remove permission by specifying permission statement id.
2. Remove lambda target from the rule
3. Delete the rule